# How to get the master suite name?

Tags: selenium, testng, appium, testng.xml

While running selenium suite files from the master file i want to get the suite name of master xml.

I tries using ISuite and ITestContext but it is returning currently running suite  name

Master :

```
<suite name="Master Suite" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="ExtentReport.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="pri_order_schemes.xml" />
        <suite-file path="pri_sale_schemes.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Suite 1:

```
<suite name="slave 1" preserve-order="false">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="ExtentReport.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Bizom Order with QTY based schemes enter QTY in units testing">
        <classes>
           <class name="orders.primaryorders." />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Suite 2:

```
<suite name="slave 2" preserve-order="false">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="ExtentReport.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Bizom Order with QTY based schemes enter QTY in units testing">
        <classes>
           <class name="orders.primaryorders." />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want to get the suite name as "Master Suite" but instead i am getting either "slave 1" or "slave 2"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using ITestResult:

```
iTestResult.getTestContext().getSuite().getName();
```

Comment: No luck :)..ItestResult also returning currently executing suite name not the master suite

Comment: then i will recommend you to put the breakpoint on method where you have instance of iTestResult and check what you can get from it. I have only one suite and lots of tests so i am not able to test it by myself.

Comment: Hi...as i mentioned in my previous comment i am getting the name of slave suite name  not the master suite name

Comment: do you run your tests in parallel or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by below

```
iTestResult.getTestContext().getSuite().getParentSuite();
```

Have a look [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/xml/XmlSuite.html#getParentSuite())